# Node.js Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, callback

I am writing a simple query to fetch all the list of courses in the mongodb. I get a {} as response, and node.js stops with the error, "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent."

Here is my schema for course collection. course.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var course = new Schema({

course : [{courseName : String}]

}, {collection : 'course'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('course', course);
```

Here is the router.get in index.js file for the query.

```
router.get('/course', function (req, res) {

  collection = db.collection('course');
  query = {};
   projection = {"_id" : 0, "course.courseName": 1};

  cursor = collection.find(query);
  cursor.project(projection);
  cursor.forEach(function (doc) {
          res.send(doc);
      },
      function (err) {
          if(err)
              throw err;
      }
  );

});
```

Here is the error which I got.

```
GET /course 200 34.808 ms - 2
/home/vikas/study/angularjs/learnAngularjsCoursera/passportAuthentication/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:175
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:356:11)
at ServerResponse.header (/home/vikas/study/angularjs/learnAngularjsCoursera/passportAuthentication/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:718:10)
at ServerResponse.send (/home/vikas/study/angularjs/learnAngularjsCoursera/passportAuthentication/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:163:12)
at ServerResponse.json (/home/vikas/study/angularjs/learnAngularjsCoursera/passportAuthentication/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:249:15)
at ServerResponse.send (/home/vikas/study/angularjs/learnAngularjsCoursera/passportAuthentication/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:151:21)
at /home/vikas/study/angularjs/learnAngularjsCoursera/passportAuthentication/routes/index.js:234:19
at /home/vikas/study/angularjs/learnAngularjsCoursera/passportAuthentication/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:773:23
at handleCallback (/home/vikas/study/angularjs/learnAngularjsCoursera/passportAuthentication/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:172:5)
at nextFunction (/home/vikas/study/angularjs/learnAngularjsCoursera/passportAuthentication/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:682:5)
at Cursor.next [as _next] (/home/vikas/study/angularjs/learnAngularjsCoursera/passportAuthentication/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:692:3)
at loop (/home/vikas/study/angularjs/learnAngularjsCoursera/passportAuthentication/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:687:8)
at _each (/home/vikas/study/angularjs/learnAngularjsCoursera/passportAuthentication/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:734:16)
at /home/vikas/study/angularjs/learnAngularjsCoursera/passportAuthentication/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:745:7
at handleCallback (/home/vikas/study/angularjs/learnAngularjsCoursera/passportAuthentication/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:96:12)
at /home/vikas/study/angularjs/learnAngularjsCoursera/passportAuthentication/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:675:5
at handleCallback (/home/vikas/study/angularjs/learnAngularjsCoursera/passportAuthentication/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:172:5)
```

Please suggest me where I am going wrong.

Comment: You cannot call `res.send(doc);` multiple times. Each request has a single response and it can only be sent once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using express, you can only make one call to `res.send` per route. In your case, it looks like you're trying to return a list of documents to the client, correct?

What you'll need to do is create an array of the objects first, then return it.

Here's how you can modify your existing route to work properly:

```
router.get('/course', function(req, res) {
  var collection = db.collection('course');
  var query = {};
  var projection = {"_id" : 0, "course.courseName": 1};
  var docs = [];

  cursor = collection.find(query);
  cursor.project(projection);

  cursor.forEach(function(doc) {
    docs.push(doc);
  }, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json({docs: docs});
  });
});
```

Comment: I did what you suggested, i'm not getting that error but in the response, I'm getting  [{},{}]. Any Idea what's going wrong here. Thanks a lot for your previous help.

Comment: I just updated the sample to return JSON instead. That might be better for your use case. Give that a try!

Comment: That means the docs your DB is returning are empty objects. Not much I can help with there :(

Comment: yea I got to know that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Can try with callback function and `return res.send` with all data.

Like:

```
router.get('/course', function (req, res) {

  var collection = db.collection('course');
  var query = {};
  var projection = {"_id" : 0, "course.courseName": 1};

  collection.find(query, projection).toArray(function (err, docs) {
      if(err) {
           return res.status(500).send({error:err.message});
      } 
      return res.status(200).send(docs);
  });

});
```

And you may used mongoose according to your question description. so you should use that instead of `collection = db.collection('course');`. First load that `course` model and then use that

```
var Course = require("course");// your course.js file path. can be like: "../model/course"

Course.find(query, projection, function (err, docs){
//... like above function 
});
```

Comment: I got error  "process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"

Comment: for first query can try `(query, projection).toArray` see updated answer but for second process should not change @VikasPandey